# jQuery $.ajax responseJSON has different values as responseText

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have really strange problem with ajax json response. The data in the json response (`jqXHR.responseJSON`) does not match the string response data (`jqXHR.responseText`). Request is without any errors (returning status code 200 OK) with json string data:

```
{"pdata":{"1":{"x":158,"y":545},"2":{"x":259,"y":179},"3":{"x":503,"y":77},"4":{"x":435,"y":528}},"status":"0","result":true}
```

I have simle code for console logging:

```
    var loadItemData = function(image) {
        var data = {};
        // Prepare request data
        data.image = image;
        data.token = $this.getOpt('token');
        // Call image get data url
        $.ajax({
            url: $this.getOpt('image_get_data_url'),
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
                console.log($.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText));
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
```

The console output from ajax success callback above is:
[image]
The question is, why responseJSON has different data as responseText and why manually parsed responseText giving right data output?
I noticed this problem after deploying changes on test server and don't have this problem on localhost (WAMP server). Using Firefox 66.0.5 (32-bit). Its developer tool showing correct data in Network tab for this request.

Comment: Did you specify `dataType: "json"` in the `$.ajax` call?

Comment: It's very strange that the first level of the object has all the correct data, it's only the nested values that are wrong. I don't see how that can happen.

Comment: Either it should parse the whole response or not, it shouldn't parse it but leave some properties set to `0`.

Comment: Can you show your ajax command please?

Comment: @Marcus whole ajax call definition added

Comment: Why dont you just use the first parameter of the `success` callback? `json` in above case.

Comment: Like @Barmar said I don't see how this is possible. My only thought is that this is possibly a caching bug within jQuery, where one property is read from cache and the other is not. Try adding `cache: false` to the request - although to be honest I'm grasping at straws to explain this behaviour.

Comment: @Chay22 totally the same values as in `jqXHR.responseJSON`. I think it's the same object anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan POST is never cached.

Comment: @Barmar yep, you're right. I have absolutely no idea how this is possible then. OP, is it possible for you to recreate this behaviour for us to see in a fiddle/snippet?

Comment: Caching isn't done by jQuery, it's done by the browser. All that `cache: false` does is add a cachebuster to the URL, it doesn't change how jQuery processes it.

Comment: Is there any code that modifies `responseJSON`? The behavior you're seeing is usually because the console shows a live version of the object. If you expand a field after it has been modified, you'll see the updated value.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan @Barmar Hm, I feel little bit embarrassed now. Yes, there WAS code that was modifying data like `json.pdata = $this.getDisplayPoints(json.pdata)` and returning wrong values (zero-s). BUT, why logging show those zero-s even i remove all modification code and left only those 3 lines for debugging? Some kind of cache?

Comment: It shouldn't happen if you removed the modification code. I think you must not really have removed it.